# Лучшее возможное подмножество

Tags: c++, алгоритм

суть проблемы  в том что дан массив из n чисел, и нужно разделить его на k подмножеств так чтобы минимальное число из сум элементов каждого из этих k подмножеств было максимально возможным

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int a[100005];

int main() {
    int n, k;
    cin >> n >> k;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        cin >> a[i];
        a[i] += a[i - 1];
    }

    if (k == 1) {
        cout << a[n];
        return 0;
    }

    int mx = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        if (mx <= min(a[i], a[n] - a[i])) {
            mx = min(a[i], a[n] - a[i]);
        }
    }

    cout << mx;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Расскажите о ваших попытках. Что-нибудь пробовали делать? Сейчас это звучит, как сделайте задание за меня, а значит оффтоп на сайте

Comment: извините, просто подумал что мое решение немного абсурдное, вот и не вставил, но сейчас вставлю

Comment: а оно решает поставленную задачу?

Comment: только для k == 2

Comment: есть какие то идеи?

Comment: Вот нафига нужен текст программы? когда у Вас хватило соображалки поставить тег [алгоритм]? Именно придуманный алгоритм и описывайте - потом преобразовать его в код не проблема. PS. Жадный - не сработает.

Comment: а есть у кого то другое решение, у меня на уме сейчас только жадный алгоритм

Answer (score 1):

Это  т.н. "задача о куче камней", по сути требуется разложить множество на подмножества как можно более близкого размера.

Жадный алгоритм лучшего решения не гарантирует, а динамическое программирование поможет только в случае  k=2.

Эта оптимизационная задача решается полным перебором, а для ускорения можно  привлечь **метод ветвей и границ** и, вероятно, др. методы комбинаторной оптимизации.

Что почитать - Романовский "Алгоритмы решения экстремальных задач"

[Пример реализации от А. Шарахова](https://delphisources.ru/pages/faq/base/stones_in_boxes.html)