# Задача о куче камней. Перебор

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Задача такая: Имеется N камней, известны их веса Pi (i=1...N), задано
количество куч M. Требуется разложить камни на M куч так, чтобы минимизировать
вес самой тяжелой кучи. Решала эту задачу таким способом: в кучу с наименьшим весом кладем самый тяжелый камень. Я же правильно понимаю, что это эвристический алгоритм? Мне нужно решить задачу именно перебором, но нет идей как сделать это для неопределенного числа куч.

Comment: А ограничения на N, M, Pi какие?

Comment: *Я же правильно понимаю, что это эвристический алгоритм?* Нет. Это один из возможных вариантов реализации жадного алгоритма. *нет идей как сделать это для неопределенного числа куч* А вот это зачем? по заданию-то количество куч вполне себе определённое, и даже где-то заданное в условии.

Comment: @Akina А для этой задачи жадный алгоритм работает? это же обычно надо доказывать?

Comment: *А для этой задачи жадный алгоритм работает?* Нет. Пример - 2 кучи, камни 2*3+3*2.

Comment: В принципе это ни что иное как задача линейного раскроя (упрощённая версия задачи о рюкзаке) - т.е. чисто NP-полная задача, решаемая только полным перебором. Подход к решению может быть такой. Сперва из исходных данных считаем теоретически минимальный вес кучи. Тут же сравниваем его с наиболее тяжёлым камнем, если камень тяжелее - корректируем. Затем перебираем все варианты полного заполнения кучи, до посчитанного предела. Для каждого варианта берём оставшиеся камни и решаем подзадачу (рекурсивно).

Comment: Таким способом либо приходим к решению, либо каждый раз на очередном шаге рекурсии расчётный вес кучи превышает таковой на предыдущем шаге - тогда всё херим и решаем задачу заново с пределом, увеличенным на 1.

Comment: @Akina "Эвристический алгоритм - алгоритм решения задачи, включающий практический метод, не являющийся гарантированно точным или оптимальным, но достаточный для решения поставленной задачи." (Вики). Учитывая, что автор вопроса не доказал оптимальность своего жадника (а вы даже показали обратное), но при этом его алгоритм решает задачу хоть с какой-то точностью, этот жадник действительно корректно называть эвристикой. Так что автор вполне правильно понимает, что его алгоритм - эвристический.

Comment: @EzikBro В данном конкретном случае жадный алгоритм не решает задачу "с какой-то точностью". Ибо "хоть с какой-то точностью" тем не менее подразумевает, что абсолютно все требования к результату - соблюдаются, тогда как жадный алгоритм не обеспечивает требования "минимизировать вес самой тяжелой кучи", сформулированного однозначно и безальтернативно.

Comment: @EzikBro Я лично предпочитаю следующее определение: "Эвристический алгоритм — это алгоритм, для которого не доказано, что он всегда даёт оптимальное решение, но про который известно,
что он даёт решение, оптимальное или близкое к оптимальному, в большинстве случаев."

Comment: @Akina в задаче коммивояжера тоже есть однозначное и безальтернативное требование минимизировать длину пути, но эвристиками мы считаем любые алгоритмы, которые дают пути и в два раза длиннее минимального. Поэтому эти алгоритмы и эвристические, что они не решают задачу в ее полных требованиях, но решают хоть в какой-то ослабленной форме - для каких частных случаев или с какой-то (может быть и очень большой) погрешностью

Comment: @EzikBro *в задаче коммивояжера тоже есть однозначное и безальтернативное требование минимизировать длину пути* - и именно поэтому решение (пока во всяком случае) возможно только полным перебором. А эвристический алгоритм именно что даёт результат, близкий к решению (или одному из решений, если их несколько). Иногда, но не всегда, и само решение. но практически всегда - несильно от решения отклоняющийся.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1167605/291659

Comment: Подозреваю, что тут бинпоиск по ответу...

Answer (score 0):

Перебор не самая эффективная стратегия решения задач, но если нужно решить перебором, то можно сделать это через рекурсию. Функция `StoneBruteForce` получает на вход:

`iStone` - номер текущего камня;

`stoneWeights` - вектор весов камней (Pi из условия задачи);

`heaps` - вектор представляющий кучи, его элементы векторы в которых хранятся веса хранимых там камней. Он имеет размер M из условия задачи;

и возвращает вес самой тяжелой кучи и распределение камней по кучам в выходном аргументе `answer`:

```
    typedef double stone_weight;
    
    stone_weight StoneBruteForce(int iStone, const std::vector<stone_weight>& stoneWeights,
      std::vector<std::vector<stone_weight>>& heaps,
      std::vector<std::vector<stone_weight>>& answer)
    {
      stone_weight maxHeapWeight = numeric_limits<stone_weight>::max();
      if (iStone == stoneWeights.size() - 1)
      {
        //Последний камень - кладем его поочередно во все кучи, считаем их 
        //веса и запоминаем ответ, если вес самой тяжелой кучи меньше чем 
        //известный.
        for (std::vector<std::vector<stone_weight>>::iterator it = heaps.begin();
             it != heaps.end(); ++it)
        {
          it->push_back(stoneWeights[iStone]);
    
          //Посчитать веса всех куч и взять кучу с самым большим весом.
          stone_weight localMaxHeapWeight = 0.0;
          for (std::vector<std::vector<stone_weight>>::iterator itH = heaps.begin();
               itH != heaps.end(); ++itH)
          {
            stone_weight heapWeight = accumulate(itH->begin(), itH->end(), 0.0);
            if (heapWeight > localMaxHeapWeight)
              localMaxHeapWeight = heapWeight;
          }
    
          //Если самая тяжелая легче чем текущая самая тяжелая, запомним ее.
          if (maxHeapWeight > localMaxHeapWeight)
          {
            maxHeapWeight = localMaxHeapWeight;
            answer = heaps;
          }
          it->pop_back();
        }
      }
      else
      {
        //Не последний камень - кладем его поочередно во все кучи и продолжаем
        //рекурсию со следующим камнем.
        for (std::vector<std::vector<stone_weight>>::iterator it = heaps.begin();
             it != heaps.end(); ++it)
        {
          it->push_back(stoneWeights[iStone]);
          std::vector<std::vector<stone_weight>> localanswer;
          stone_weight localMaxHeapWeight = StoneBruteForce(iStone + 1, 
                                         stoneWeights, heaps, localanswer);
          if (maxHeapWeight > localMaxHeapWeight)
          {
            maxHeapWeight = localMaxHeapWeight;
            answer = localanswer;
          }
          it->pop_back();
        }
      }
      return maxHeapWeight;
    }
    
    void print_answer(stone_weight maxHeapWeight, 
                      std::vector<std::vector<stone_weight>>& answer)
    {
      int iHeap = 0;
      std::cout << "Max heap weight " << maxHeapWeight << std::endl;
      for (auto h : answer)
      {
        std::cout << "Heap " << iHeap << " stones";
        for (auto w : h)
          std::cout << " " << w;
        std::cout << std::endl;
        iHeap++;
      }
    }
```

Вызываем так

```
  std::vector<stone_weight> stoneWeights = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
  std::vector<std::vector<stone_weight>> heaps(3);
  stone_weight maxHeapWeight = StoneBruteForce(0, stoneWeights, heaps, answer);
  print_answer(minWeightDiff, answer);
```

Введенные пользователем веса камней надо положить в `stoneWeights` и изменить размер `heaps` на количество куч.